# Show the ID of referenced entities using tokens, instead of the label with link

Tags: 8, nodes, tokens

I have a content type, Company, which is referenced to a User with an entity reference. The token for that entity reference for the current user is     `[current-user:field_user_company]`.

No matter how I configure the field I'm using the token in, when using this token, it always translates in a the label with a link `<a href="/node/17" hreflang="en">TEST COMPANY</a>.`

Is there any way I could make this token translate into just the Node ID (17 in this case)?  I would need just the ID to pass the reference on to other entities in a workflow (using Rules or Business Rules).

Comment: Not sure what version of Drupal you're using (not sure it even matters actually), but try `[current-user:field_user_company:entity:nid]`

Comment: Thanks.  But, no, that didn't work (for Drupal 8).  The token doesn't translate at all (empty output).

Comment: Maybe `[current-user:field_user_company:0:entity:nid`] or `[current-user:field_user_company:0:entity:id`]`?

Comment: Or possibly `[current-user:field_user_company:target_id]` or `[current-user:field_user_company:0:target_id]`

Comment: Yes!   [current-user:field_user_companies_represented:target_id] did the trick. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the solution given by Clive in the comments to my question as an answer :

```
[current-user:field_user_company:target_id]
```

= the token translating into the node ID of a referenced content type.